# Apply functions to values of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list `L` of dictionaries, where the dictionaries have the same set of keys.

I have another dictionary `d`, which also has the same set of keys as the previous dictionaries.

For each `key` in the set of keys, `d[key]` is a function which can apply to `L[i][key]`, i.e. `d[key](L[i][key])`.

I want to reset the values of dictionaries in `L`, using the functions in the values of `d`, i.e.

```
L[i][key] = d[key](L[i][key])
```

for all `key` and all `i`.

How can I do it in a more pythonic way? Thanks.

E.g.

```
d = {'a':int, 'b':myfun, 'c':yourfun}

L[1] = {'a':`10`, 'b':5, 'c':1.4}
```

where `int` is a type conversion function `int()`, `myfun` is a function which can take an integer as its argument, and `yourfun` is another function which can take a floating number as its argument.

Comment: an example would be better.

Comment: Oh man. I'd say there's no pythonic way to do an unpythonic thing. Can you reach your goal in a way that doesn't involve taking this approach?

Comment: Ideally, I think you should have one big dictionary like so: `{'key1': {'fn':func, 'L': [L[0]['key1'], L[1]['key1'], etc. ]}, 'key2': ... etc }` If all of the data is related to the key, it should be grouped by key, no? Why use separate dictionaries that have the same keysets?

Comment: @Shashank: Thanks for asking. I also have the same question. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136156/representing-a-relational-database-a-list-of-dictionaries-or-a-dictionary-with

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can regenerate `L` with the correct values using a list and dict comprehension:

```
L = [{k: d[k](v) for (k, v) in l.iteritems()} for l in L]
```

Comment: Thanks. All the given dictionaries are collections.OrderedDict, and have the same orders in their keys. Your way will create an unordered dictionary. How can I create a collections.OrderedDict in the same order as the given dictionaries?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136222/create-ordered-dict-from-list-comprehension