# Representing a relational database: a list of dictionaries or a dictionary with list values?

Tags: python, database, dictionary

A relational database has a schema and a set of records

I have two ways of representing a relational database in Python:

- create a list of dictionaries with the same set of keys, where the keys is the attribute names of the schema, and each dictionary represents a record.
- create a dictionary, where its keys are the attribute names of the schema, and the value for each key is a list of values of the corresponding attribute in the records.

I wonder which way may be easier to operate, or have more readily avaiable functions to apply? Which way may work more similarly to a relational database?

Does Python have some other (better) data structures/types to represent the same thing?

E.g.

a relational database is a table:

```
name  age
Joe   10
Mary  6
Tim   8
```

The first way gives

```
[{name:Joe,age:10}, {name:Mary,age:6}, {name:Tim,age:8}]
```

The second way gives

```
{name:[Joe,Mary,Tim],age:[10,6,8]}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `which way may be easier to operate, or have more readily avaiable functions to apply` - It depends on the operations you are going to perform on the data.

Comment: in terms of similar operations in relational database

Comment: In my opinion, I would use the first method for listing records from the DB (or doing any operation on a set of rows, e.g. a filter), and use the second one for applying operations on specific columns of the DB (which is what your question dealt with earlier).

Comment: Why is that? @Shashank

Comment: Because iteration through a list is efficient in most Python implementations. If you are applying an operation to a set of rows (like printing out all the rows to a webpage, or filtering the rows based on age, etc), then it's faster (performance-wise) and cleaner (especially due to list comprehensions) to use way 1. If the desired operation needs to be applied to a column in a table, then you can just iterate through the list provided in method 2, for example adding 2 to every age is simply `d['age'] = [a+2 for a in d['age']]` which is Pythonic.

Comment: You may want to check out [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)

Comment: there has a third way, a list of column name, and use a list to represent a record. in this way, iter over row or column both will be efficient.