# create ordered dict from list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

[Here is a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29135851/156458):

```
L = [{k: d[k](v) for (k, v) in l.iteritems()} for l in L]
```

where

- `L` is a list  of ordered dictionaries (i.e. objects of collections.OrderedDict), where the dictionaries have the same set of keys.
- `d` is another ordered dictionary, which also has the same set of keys as the previous ordered dictionaries.
- For each `key`, `d[key]` is a function which can apply to `L[i][key]`, i.e. `d[key](L[i][key])`.

All the given dictionaries are ordered dicts, and have the same order in their keys.

But the code will create an unordered dictionary. How can I create an ordered dict in the same key order as the given ordered dictionaries?

Answer (score 9):

`collections.OrderedDict` is nothing but a dict, which remembers the order in which the elements are included in it. So you can create one with its constructor like this

```
[OrderedDict((k, d[k](v)) for (k, v) in l.iteritems()) for l in L]
```

Comment: Why isnt the dict Ordered?

```from collections import OrderedDict
dict1 =  OrderedDict({x: x**5 for x in (1, 5, 10)}).__class__
ord_dict = OrderedDict({x: x**5 for x in (1, 5, 10)})
print(ord_dict) 
# OrderedDict([(1, 1), (10, 100000), (5, 3125)])```

Comment: @RohitDhankar You have already created a dictionary in your case. The data is already unordered in memory. `OrderedDict` has nothing to do with the unexpected order here.

Answer (score 4):

Python dictionary unlike C++ dictionary are unordered because it uses hash for its keys. Analternative would be to use an ordered specialization of python dictionary called [collections.OrdredDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

This would turn your declaration as

```
from collections import OrderedDict
L = [OrderedDict((k, d[k](v)) for (k, v) in l.iteritems()) for l in L]
```